# Meu código de teste está da seguinte forma:

Tags: php

```
<?
    session_start();
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome');
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;  

  ?>
  <form action="teste.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="nome"> <br> <br>
    <button>Enviar</button>
  </form>

<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SESSION['nome'] == 'sim' ) {
    echo 'Logado'; // Ele não entra aqui
  } else {
    header('location: index.php?login=erro'); // Ele so fica na pagina index, independente do valor passado no input
  }
```

---

Agora se eu fizer dessa forma ele loga, porém ele loga o usuário independente do valor passado no input

```
session_start();

  if($_SESSION['nome'] != 'sim' ) {
    echo 'Logado'; //Ele entra aqui
  } else {
    header('location: index.php?login=erro');
  }
```

Comment: SIm a minha logica seria essa, porém qualquer valor que eu digite incluindo o sim ele entra no logado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();

  if($_SESSION['nome'] != 'sim' ) {
    header('location: index.php?login=erro');
  } else {
    echo 'Logado'; //Ele entra aqui;
  }
```

N a sintaxe do IF o `==` É para comparar se o valor é igual e qunado esta como `!=` mostra que seja diferente, ou seja, seria um else dentro da comparação.... o correto é inverter.